# Extract array element with maximum property value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, underscore.js, lodash

I have a JS array of objects

```
const a = [
  {name: karl, age: 53}, 
  {name: fred, age: 34}, 
  {name: annie, age: 12},
  // ...
];
```

and I would like to extract the objects with the maximum `age`. I could perhaps sort the entire array and just pick the first element, but that seems somewhat wasteful.

Comment: getting max age from a collection example http://underscorejs.org/#max

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use `_.max`, like this

```
console.log(_.max(a, 'age'));
```